# Why can't packer create HVM AMI for linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm guessing packer is using outdated boto libraries or something?

```
==> amazon-ebs: Error launching source instance: Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type. (InvalidParameterCombination)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're using an instance type that doesn't support hvm.

See this table:

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/